# interlis/ili2gpkg: export to XTF with multiple geometries

Tags: interlis

I am trying to export a XTF-File from a geopackage with ili2gpkg. The Interlis-Model is KbS_Basis_V1_4/KbS_LV95_V1_4. The data consists of point-features (table "belastete_standorte") from which some also have an additional polygon-geometry (table "polygonstructure"). The data export via

```
java -jar ili2gpkg.jar --export --models KbS_LV95_V1_4;KbS_Basis_V1_4 --dbfile kbs.gpkg kbs.xtf
```

passes without errors, but when reimporting the XTF-file the features only appear with point geometries. I suspect that I am missing some export option that states the data consists also of polygon geometries. 
For creating the scheme I use:

```
java -jar ili2gpkg.jar --schemaimport --dbfile schema.gpkg --models KbS_LV95_V1_4;KbS_Basis_V1_4
```

I am using version 4.3.0 (2019-09-20).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved: There has been a polygon in "polygonstructure" without a correspondent feature in "belastete_standorte".